# For all possible values of $b \le 0$ solve $\frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}{x} \ge b$ for $x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

The **answer**:

For $b \le -1$, $x \in \left( -\infty; -1 \right] \cup \left[1; +\infty \right)$; for $-1 \lt b \le 0$, $x \in \left(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1 - b^2}}; -1\right] \cup \left[1; +\infty \right)$.

I've showed that for every $b \le 0$, $x \in \left[1; +\infty \right)$. The other part of the answer got me pondering: why does it matter whether $b \le -1$ or $-1 \lt b \le 0$? How do I express $x$ in terms of $b$?

Comment: Under root expression cant be negative and division by zero is undefined

Comment: @SujithZis thank you, I know that $x \le -1$ or $x \ge 1$. It didn't really help me so far.

Comment: No, that is exactly backward.  In order for the square root to be a real number, $0< x\le 1$ or $-1\le x< 0$

Comment: @user247327 I don't think I understand you correctly, but $x^2 - 1 \ge 0$ is when $|x| \ge 1$, isn't it?

Comment: Express $x$ in terms of b alone first by taking  $x$ inside the root , squaring both sides , reciprocal and take square root of both sides , and then think about it . ie: $\frac{\pm1}{\sqrt{1 - b^2}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why does it matter whether $b≤−1$ or $−1<b≤0$ ?

We have $x^2-1\ge 0\iff x\le -1\quad\text{or}\quad x\ge 1$.

For $x\ge 1$, the inequality holds.

For $x\le -1$, we have
$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}\ge b\iff \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{-x}\le -b\iff \left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{-x}\right)^2\le (-b)^2$$$$\iff \frac{x^2-1}{x^2}\le b^2\iff x^2-1\le b^2x^2\iff (b^2-1)x^2\ge -1$$
Here, whether $b\le -1$ or $-1\lt b\le 0$ matters.

Comment: Looks good but why are you multiplying by $-1$ in the first place?

Comment: @PaulVergeev: I made the both sides non-negative. Then, I used that $A\le B\iff A^2\le B^2$ for $A\ge 0,B\ge 0$.